# Exporting as PDF VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue trying to adjust a macro to export as pdf rather than a .dox

```
    ' Find the last record of the Mail Merge data
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdLastRecord
    lastRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord

    ' Ask for user confirmation to start creating the documents
    If MsgBox(lastRecord & " documents will be created based on your Mail Merge template.", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
        ' Ask for the name of the Merge Field name to use for the document names
        docNameField = InputBox("Which Mergefield [name] should be used for document name?")

        ' Create document for each Mail Merge record (loop)
        For rec = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord To lastRecord
            ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = rec

            ' Set document name for current record
            If Trim(docNameField) = "" Then
                strDocName = "document" & rec & ".docx"
            Else
                strDocName = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields(docNameField).Value & ".docx"
            End If

            ' Execute Mail Merge action
            With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
                .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                .Execute
            End With

            ' Save generated document and close it after saving
            ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=savePath & strDocName
            ActiveDocument.Close False

            ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
        Next rec

        ' Re-enable screen visuals
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Else 'if no destination folder was selected
        'Re-enable screen visuals
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

I have tried to utilise activedocument.exportasfixedformat but cannot get this to work. Id appreciate any guidance.

Regards

Comment: Why not just end the `End If` before the `Application.ScreenUpdating` & `DisplayAlerts` so you don't have to type it twice? Short code _generally_ (not always - in your case however) leads to improved readability. This doesn't answer your question which is why it's in the comment section instead as an answer.

Comment: `ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=savePath & strDocName` is simply "saving as" which will cause Word to save in its default `docx` format. Where's the code that does the `.ExportAsFixedFormat` and what kind of errors does it throw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said you should use ExportAsFixedFormat, something like this.

```
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat _
 OutputFileName:=savePath & strDocName & ".pdf", _
 ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
```

Comment: Hi Apologies I now have an additional problem. the file name is set by the mailmerge source but it can only find one of them. I get a runtime 5941 when selecting a mailmerge source field as the name for the file but this doesnt happen to every mail merger source

Comment: How your datasource look like? When you che k in the Word document can you see more records in the Mailing ribbon?

Comment: Hi yes i can see more than one records within the mailing ribbon. Its strange the program runs correctly with a specific mail merge source header but not the rest. I tested with a test document and data source and a similar issue happened

Comment: Do you input a valid fieldname when the msgbox appears? Like [fileName]? It should be a column name in square brackets, if it contains space swap it with an underscore _ eg.: Document File Name becomes [Document_File_Name].

Comment: And Delete the .docx append too pretty useless

Comment: Thanks Matray. unfortunatley the isse still persists. My mailmerge source data looks like the following; and i have used square brackets with non of my headers including a space

Comment: name address DOB ( with data underneath each header of course).

Comment: the debug points me to the following line of code;                                                                             strDocName=ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields(docNameField).Value & ".docx"

Comment: I would need the datasource and word doc to find anything else, try debugging it step by step, add a watch to strDocName and  ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields(docNameField).Value. try using differend datafieldnames etc

Comment: Thank you. Rookie error the mailmerge data source contained invalid characters! Thanks for your guidance. I will probaly remove the message dialog box and select a static naming value

Comment: Probably for the best :D or let them choose from a list that contains the datasource's fieldnames.